# Drawing Rectangle on Mapbox gl

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Any Idea about Drawing Rectangle on Mapbox GL like we draw Polygon in [This Demo](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/)

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not supported in `mapbox-gl-draw`, but according to [this github issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/issues/604) it's in the works.

Comment: Someone created an open source rectangle draw https://github.com/edgespatial/mapbox-gl-draw-rectangle-mode